# Rails 4: Jquery code only renders sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a piece of Jquery code that once a user signups the first time and goes to the page where I have Jquery code loaded it doesn't work, but once I reload the page it displays fine. It seems as though this happens every time I make an account and then go to that page the code doesn't display.
I have included in my application.rb `config.assets.precompile += %w( finder.js )` and rendered the Javascript in the html through `<%= javascript_include_tag "finder.js" %>` 

 **What could be making the code not render upon signup, performance issues?**

Here is my code:
**Form.html.erb**

```
<!-- multistep form -->


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="margin-top text-center">
      <h2 class="bg-success">Answer each question, &amp; we match you with your ideal career choice!</h2>
    </div>
        <div class="margin-little-top">
<form id="msform">

    <fieldset id="firstField">

        <h2 class="fs-title">Are you Technical or Creative?</h2>

        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>

        <input type="button" name="technical" class="next action-button" value="Technical" />

        <input type="button" name="creative" class="next action-button" value="Creative" />

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="technicalField">
        <h2 class="fs-title">You walk into a room at a party, do you go to the center of the room or stay on the periphery?</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 2</h3>


        <input type="button" name="algebra" class="next action-button" value="Algebra" />
        <input type="button" name="geometry" class="next action-button" value="Geometry" />
        <br>
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />

    </fieldset>

      <fieldset id="algebraField">
        <h2 class="fs-title">Algebra</h2>
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="geometryField">
        <h2 class="fs-title">Geometry</h2>
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    </fieldset>

<!------##################Sciences#####################---->

    <fieldset id="creativeField">
        <h2 class="fs-title">Creative</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Do you like Chemistry or Biology?</h3>
       <input type="button" name="chemistry" class="next action-button" value="chemistry" />

       <input type="button" name="biology" class="next action-button" value="Biology" />
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="chemistryField">
        <h2 class="fs-title">Chemistry</h2>

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="biologyField">
        <h2 class="fs-title">Biology</h2>

    </fieldset>

</form>
</div></div></div>


<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- jQuery easing plugin -->
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery.easing.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

<%= javascript_include_tag "finder.js" %>
```

**finder.js**

```
//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs, maths_fs, science_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;
    current_fs = $(this).parent();


    if($(this).attr('name') == 'technical')
        next_fs = $('#technicalField');
     if($(this).attr('name') == 'algebra')
        next_fs = $('#technicalField');
     if($(this).attr('name') == 'geometry')
        next_fs = $('#technicalField');



    if($(this).attr('name') == 'creative')
        next_fs = $('#creativeField');
    if($(this).attr('name') == 'chemistry')
        next_fs = $('#chemistryField');
    if($(this).attr('name') == 'biology')
        next_fs = $('#biologyField');

    //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

    //show the next fieldset
    next_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
            left = (now * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
            next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $('#firstField');

    //de-activate current step on progressbar
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

    //show the previous fieldset
    previous_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
            scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
            left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'left': left});
            previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is a turbolinks related problem. Check out this question:

[Rails 4: how to use $(document).ready() with turbo-links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links)

The problem with turbolinks is that when you follow a link to a page or submit a form, it doesn't let the browser recompile the entire page. Instead, it replaces the body of the page. Leaving some of your javascript on the side of the road.

You can either look at the SO question linked above for a way to work with turbolinks, or you can simply remove turbolinks altogether.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Have fun!

Comment: I recommend using `$(document).on 'ready page:load', ->` instead of the accepted answer on that question. Just my .02.

Comment: I just went ahead and used the jquery turbolinks gem